# why am i getting FatalExecutionEngineError

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-4.6

i'm running this code

```
var existing =( from r in DB.Database.Entities.OfType<DBWorkReport>()
              where Math.Round(r.Location.Latitude ?? 0, 6) == Math.Round(latitude, 6)
              && Math.Round(r.Location.Longitude ?? 0, 6) == Math.Round(longitude, 6)
              && r.WorkType.Description == type
              select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

the error also occurs on a simple 
DB.Database.Entities.ToList();

where

DB is

```
public class DatabaseInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public void Initialise()
    {
        if (Database == null)
        {
            Database = new DataDBEntities();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DataDBEntities _Database;
    public static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs DatabaseProperty = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Database));


    public DataDBEntities Database
    {
        get { return _Database; }
        set
        {
            _Database = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, DatabaseProperty);
        }
    }
```

Entities is

```
public virtual DbSet<DBEntity> Entities { get; set; }
```

DBWorkReport is

```
public partial class DBWorkReport : DBEntity
```

and r.Location is DBGeography

however when i run it, its throwing

> FatalExecutionEngineError occurred   HResult=-2146233082
>   Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was
>   thrown.   InnerException:

[image]

to quote MSDN:

> FatalExecutionEngineError: 
>   This type previously indicated an unspecified fatal error in the
>   runtime. The runtime no longer raises this exception so this type is
>   obsolete.

at a another point i'm successfully calling this code so it doesn't seem that the problem is the connection to SQLServer

```
lookups = DB.Database?.Lookups.Where(l=>l.companyid==DB.CompanyID).ToLookup(g => g.LookupTypeId) ;
```

so what's not working?

Update:

from DB

```
SELECT *,
      [Location].ToString() as WKT
  FROM [WorkReport]

Id  TypeID  ProximityId lineID  Location    WKT
178 6   2   7   0xE6100000010C8743DC9D754E4A40EB4B08A5400102C0  POINT (-2.25061158114976 52.6129643750674)
179 4   2   7   0xE6100000010CC4A6BF62F7504A40F9ACC89EB70602C0  POINT (-2.25327991533197 52.6325496135519)
180 7   2   7   0xE6100000010CAFC1F420EF624A40D795D41A58F301C0  POINT (-2.24382039033183 52.7729226298428)
181 7   3   7   0xE6100000010C988B36673E654A40E049A63A0BEA01C0  POINT (-2.23927923030827 52.7909668938002)
182 6   2   7   0xE6100000010CF3D11F539F8B4A4028430DF623DE02C0  POINT (-2.35846702793096 53.0907997041103)
183 8   2   8   0xE6100000010C82B9B41004534A40F97B9728ECDEF8BF  POINT (-1.55442443710467 52.6485615618176)
184 4   2   6   0xE6100000010C8A8A301567434A409AFAF6A6232BFEBF  POINT (-1.88553204746828 52.5265833365457)
185 9   2   4   0xE6100000010CBB7D019FD8404A40BD903C1DCA5902C0  POINT (-2.29384253350335 52.5066107518464)
186 8   2   4   0xE6100000010CF2EDF4D773134A406773A2484D9907C0  POINT (-2.94985443826447 52.1519727655358)
187 6   1   4   0xE6100000010C381064A1F6F849408310A651BCD10CC0  POINT (-3.60240997112311 51.94502656351)
188 2   3   4   0xE6100000010CD3FCB73E6AF3494087D7B17DB7950EC0  POINT (-3.82310388754826 51.9016798399331)
189 2   1   4   0xE6100000010C44BB08BD5EED4940C320C2BF4A9610C0  POINT (-4.14676952001918 51.8544536869654)
190 6   2   4   0xE6100000010C0124660902D8494019DDE9B866BC13C0  POINT (-4.93398560454741 51.6875621556028)
191 1   2   4   0xE6100000010CF135C7CD4DDD494082104C75780714C0  POINT (-5.00729544903527 51.7289368841847)
```

Comment: Is maybe `r.Location` null?

Comment: Have you checked the inner exception for details?

Comment: @rene added content of location no nulls present

Comment: @JohnH  innerexception is null

Comment: Is `r.WorkType` null?  I can't see why it would throw that exception if it was, but, still, it's best to rule out the simple things first.

Comment: @JohnH that would throw a nullReference exception not a FatalExecutionEngineError, but updated query nothing in table is null

Comment: I agree, so the next step to take would be splitting up the query.  I'd run the query first, simply selecting all of the types without applying the `where` filter, and see what happens.  If that runs correctly, gradually add each condition to the query until you can narrow down the part that's blowing up.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say on the question `DB.Database.Entities.ToList();` throws the error to

Comment: I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the EntityFramework nugget package and of course rebooting the system

Comment: Can you leave out the where clause for the Location and handle that after you materialized the query result with ToList() and then execute that  Location where clause to see if that gets rid of the error

Comment: I've created a test project locally and I'm unable to reproduce the issue with `DB.Database.Entities.ToList();`.

Comment: looking at the other instances where this obsolete error crops up I'm beginning to wonder if a satellite DLL has been corrupted somewhere as it ems to mostly be linked to faulty PInvoke's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code being highlighted by visual studio, actually had nothing to do with the error, it was an earlier section of code that was using the GDAL libraries to re-project the North and East reference to Long/Lat, the code itself was working but something about that library was clearly causing the error as it ceased the second i removed that code

```
using (OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference inSpatialRef = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(""))
using (OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference outSpatialRef = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(""))
{
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(form);
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(to);

    using (OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation coordTransform = new OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef))
    {
        coordTransform.TransformPoint(cord);
    }
}
return cord;
```

which suggests that the issue is in the osr_csharp.dll provided as part of the GDAL package

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem and I know that is an osr_csharp.dll issue, but how did you solved it? Which version did you use? I'm I missing some reference?

Comment: unfortunately it was trial and error as to how i found it i basicallty just started commenting out code until it worked. the final solution was to not use GDAL and switch to  DotSpatial.Projections it has a nuget package

Answer (score 0):

Try casting Latitude and Longitude to (double), when calling Math.Round():

```
var existing =( from r in DB.Database.Entities.OfType<DBWorkReport>()
          where Math.Round((double)r.Location.Latitude ?? 0, 6) == Math.Round(latitude, 6)
          && Math.Round((double)r.Location.Longitude ?? 0, 6) == Math.Round(longitude, 6)
          && r.WorkType.Description == type
          select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

make sure 'longitude' and 'latitude' are of type 'double' too.

Comment: that would be an InvalidCastException and all longs and lats are already doubles thanks for trying though